# GroebnerBasis without specifying variables

Tags: polynomials, implementation-details, groebner-bases

All the examples in the *Mathematica* documentation specify that the syntax for the `GroebnerBasis` command is

```
GroebnerBasis[{poly1,poly2,...},{x1,x2,...}]
```

however it does return a result when ran just as

```
GroebnerBasis[{poly1,poly2,...}]
```

(although it does put a red caret in at the end, indicating it is missing an expected second parameter). I assume that, in this case, `GroebnerBasis` makes some choice for the variables. My intuition was that it would be `GroebnerBasis[polys] == GroebnerBasis[polys, Variables[polys]]`, but that does not seem to be the case. What is the behavior of the `GroebnerBasis` command without a variable specification?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the (ordered) list of variables is not specified, `GroebnerBasis` will order the variables as it encounters them. I remark that, as this depends on implementation details, it can be version dependent.

The question (which I should have anticipated) was raised as to how one might get the "variables" that `GroebnerBasis` sees, and in the same order. It can be done with a non-System-context function `` GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList ``. It will both rewrite the polynomials in an internal format (as its name implies), and also give the variables in the order it is using them. One must specify `CoefficientDomain -> Rationals` in order to force it to create new variables rather than treat unspecified ones as part of the coefficient field (the default behavior).

Here is a simple example.

```
polys = {3*y*z - 5, 2*x^2 + y + z^3 - 1, x*y - 2};
Variables[polys]    
Out[1]= {x, y, z}

GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[polys, CoefficientDomain -> Rationals]
Out[2]= {{{{{1, 1, 0}, 3}, {{0, 0, 0}, -5}}, {{{1, 0, 0}, 1}, {{0, 3, 0}, 1}, 
    {{0, 0, 2}, 2}, {{0, 0, 0}, -1}}, {{{1, 0, 1},1}, {{0, 0, 0}, -2}}}, {y, z, x}}
```

Comment: Any way to get a list of the variables ordered in this way? I think the "Variables[polys]" command reorders them on it's own.

Comment: @Michael See edit.

Comment: Thank you, your expertise has been extremely valuable to me. I hope Wolfram pays you well.

Comment: No, but they nowadays let me turn off the lights at night; 24 hours of fluorescence was really starting to make me feral. Brett says I should also mention the tip jar...

Comment: @process91 @DanielLichtblau Although this is way after the fact, I've had what I think was a similar problem, with a `Module` I wrote myself on Mma v9 for OS X, and then tried to run on my Mma v10 for RPi, which had a single input argument, but added the red caret as if it expected a second one.  I haven't figured out the reason and can't run the code at this point.  Might this be a version issue with `Module` between v9 and v10?

Comment: @iwantmyphd Unlikely, but without seeing the code it's impossible to say for sure what is going on.